# Copy and Modify a Sharepoint Designer 2007 Workflow

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint Designer 2010 the option there is an option to "Copy and Modify" a workflow based on an existing workflow template such as "Approval, Collect Feedback or Collect Signatures".

Is there a way to copy and modify these templates in SharePoint Designer 2007?

The change I want to make is minor and I would prefer to avoid a Visual Studio custom workflow.

I have tried to create the workflow from scratch using designer but the "Workflow Initiation Parameters" does not contains a "Person or Group" field to choose from, with an OOTB approval workflow people can selected on the initiation form to carry out the approval.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching I have not found a way to copy the OOTB workflow to make minor edits. I looks like the only way to achieve this would be to use a Visual Studio Workflow.